# Why jquery. On () not working for dynamic Element?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to have the authority to send my information via $.ajax() when (at the time) I click the update button,But I can not handel the update button click event.

I want the code to handle the update button click event but I did not work

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/Dyb9Y/19/embedded/result/)

code:

```
 $(".table").on("click", "k-grid-update", (function () {

        alert('xxx');

        //$.ajax({

        //    url: 'api/apdevice',
        //    type: 'PUT',
        //    datatype: 'application/json',
        //    data: {},
        //    success: function (data) {

        //    },

        //    error: function (data) {

        //    }

        //});
```

thank you

Comment: Maybe you're using jQUery version that doesn't support `.on()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that it is not working: the problem is that KendoUI redefined the action for that same element.

You should not directly bind it to the button but use some of KendoUI provided mechanism for doing it. Either you use [`save`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-save) event in Kendo Grid or define a convenient [`update`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.update) function on `DataSource.transport`.

Example:

```
$('.table').kendoGrid({
    dataSource : {
        transport: {
            read  : function (op) {
                op.success(data)
            },
            update: function (op) {
                alert("xxx - update");
                ...
            }
        },
        schema   : {
            model: {
                id: "Mac"
            }
        }
    },
    sortable   : true,
    groupable  : true,
    selectable : true,
    navigatable: true,
    height     : 500,
    scrollable : true,
    pageable   : true,

    rowTemplate   : kendo.template($("#client-row-template").html().replace('class="k-alt"', '')),
    altRowTemplate: kendo.template($("#client-row-template").html()),//@class="k-alt"@
    editable      : "popup",
    save          : function (a) {
        alert("xxx - save");
        ...
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".table").on("click", "k-grid-update",
```

There's your problem. You most likely want a class selector for the delegate since no HTML tag named `k-grid-update` exists:

```
$(".table").on("click", ".k-grid-update",
```

Comment: And the `(` before function should be removed.

Comment: @ZippyV: True, but it doesn't really matter since he has a `)`, too. `foo` and `(foo)` are usually the same.